# Validating combination of values in constructor

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to make a class `Box<T>`. It should have two public immutable(`val`) properties,  `isContentMandatory: Boolean`, `content: T?`. This is which combination of values I want to accept:

| isContentMandatory | content | Should allow? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| false | null | YES |
| false | non-null | YES |
| true | null | NO |
| true | non-null | YES |

I want to make sure that the constructor(s) I provide won't allow the illegal state of an object. Also, I want multiple constructors(or use default values) so that creation of an object is *straight-forward* for the client. Following are examples of instantiations:

```kotlin
Box()                        // OK -> isContentMandatory = false, content = null
Box("some-content")          // OK -> isContentMandatory = false, content = "some-content"
Box(false, "some-content")   // OK -> isContentMandatory = false, content = "some-content"
Box(true, "some-content")    // OK -> isContentMandatory = true, content = "some-content"
Box(true, null)              // DON'T ALLOW
Box(true)                    // DON'T ALLOW
```

The `DON'T ALLOW`s from above should preferably be forbidden at compile-time(no constructor available for that combination) if it's possible. Otherwise, fail with the exception during creation.

I'm coming from Java world so all those primary/secondary constructors, default values and etc. are a bit fuzzy so please explain along with a solution. I'm also open to different class design if it supports the same business logic.

**EDIT:** this is how it would look in Java.

```java
public class Box<T> {

    private final boolean isContentMandatory;
    private final T content;

    public Box() {
        this(null);
    }

    public Box(T content) {
        this(false, content);
    }
    
    public Box(boolean isContentMandatory, T content) {
        if (isContentMandatory && content == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid combination of parameters");
        }
        this.isContentMandatory = isContentMandatory;
        this.content = content;
    }

    ...getters...
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here? If you have to avoid null then `Box(..., private val content: String)`, non nullable `String` as type and that's it

Comment: I'm ok with `content` being `null`. See the first row of instantiation examples. I'll code of how it would look in Java.

Comment: Is null content equivalent to ""?

Comment: The class I'm making needs to be generic. I can't have non-null stub value for genric class at compile time. Requiring a client to provide a stub is not an option since the stub itself might have a bunch of mandatory initialization arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not this is a good approach for the problem is hard to answer without actual domain knowledge of your use case, but it feels to me like it makes little sense that you would make a single class to model those cases which carries around an (otherwise pointless?) boolean to separate the cases.

You could just have 2 classes BoxWithOptionalcontent<T?> and BoxWithContent<T> and you wouldn't need more than the default constructor for either afaict.

```
sealed interface Box<T: Any?> {
    abstract val content: T?
}
data class BoxWithContent<T: Any>(override val content: T): Box<T>
data class BoxWithOptionalContent<T: Any?>(override val content: T? = null): Box<T?>
```

This shouldn't change much on the initialization site, on the side of the usage you will probably need to add a case statement to decide which case it is and handle appropriately. But you probably already have some similar logic there anyway, and this will probably be a bit more typesafe and readable.

Comment: A small suggestion: you could make the sealed class generic, and add `abstract val content T?`. The `WithContent` variant can then have `override val content: T`, because any non-null type is a subtype of its nullable type.

Comment: Do `WithContent` and `WithoutContent` have same supertype so they can be stored in same collection?

Comment: @StjepanJakovac made a typo, they need to inherit from box, but yes now they can both be used as a Box and come with the advantage of a sealed class/interface (exhaustive `when` giving you more compile time safety at the calling sites), I also messed up the upper bounds on T, causing them to accept nulls, it is fixed now and I added the remark from aSemy to make Box generic as well

Comment: @aSemy thanks, I somehow hadn't considered that sealed interfaces/classes could also be generic, that does make the usage a lot more similar to the original Box<T>

Comment: @somethingsomething Aside from ensuring the correct constructor is called, the other benefit of sealed classes/interfaces is that when you check the type of a `Box<*>` ([for example, with a `when` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes-and-when-expression)), you can easily determine if `content` is nullable. E.g. `if (box is BoxWithContent<Int>) val i: Int = box.content` - the type of `i` is `Int`, not `Int?`.

Comment: @somethingsomething Why did `data class BoxWithContent<T>(val content: T)` accept a null value in the first place? How come is upper bound `Any` necessary? I thought that the whole point of `T` vs `T?` is to deal with nullability. Also, what's the purpose of `:Any?` on `Box` and `BoxWithOptionalContent`?

Comment: <T?> isn't a thing, you can't specify nullability of generics that way, you need to define the upper bound with or without question mark. <T> is exactly the same as <T: Any?> I just wrote it that way to show the difference with the non nullable one.  I am however not too familiar with generics so I had to google a bit around to get it right as well, this gives some other examples: https://medium.com/@igorwojda/kotlin-deep-dive-into-generics-nullability-9853d9a9f50d

Answer (score 1):

From your Java approach it seems you just want a runtime check, not really preventing bad calls. Just having default arguments and one `init` block to validate should work:

```
class Box(val content: T? = null, val isContentMandatory: Boolean = false)
     init {
         if(content == null && isContentMandatory)
             throw RuntimeException("Cannot have no content if content is mandatory")
     }
}
```

Any content given though as a first argument will be valid, so to make this break you have to try harder using `Box(isContentMandatory=true)` or `Box(null, true)` explicitly.

Comment: I was hoping the primary constructor can be such that I can add a secondary constructor which only accepts `content: T`  and `isContentMandatory: Boolean`. That way your second example would fail at compile time (but that is conflicting overload with cuurent primary constructor). As for the Java example, it has runtime check since the language doesn't have non-nullable types. I would prefer comiple-time check

Comment: @sjakovac I see what you mean, but no matter how you turn it around, in the end you want a runtime decision - do I allow construction based on the value of a variable (which is technically only known at run time), so you are going to have to compromise that, in any language. The other answer delegates the responsibility to the user of the object to decide what they want - moving the decision to compile time.